# opening files from sharepoint 2010 in office 2013 is not possible anymore

Tags: 2010, office-integration

We have lots of documents in various sharepoint 2010 sites. I used to open those files in Office 2013 - Word and Excel, but cannot do this anymore.

When i click on file in library and select "Edit" or "Read" the word or excel fires up but the file wont load. There is no error, no login prompt, nothing.

When i try to use "Open from" in Excel or Word then navigate to sharepoint then select file and click open the result is identical.

Answer (score 1):

deleting files in

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache

worked for me